# Install ocaml bytes module on debian?

Tags: debian, ocaml, liquidsoap

I am trying to install liquidsoap from source. While execution ./configure script, I saw following error:

```
****** Configuring OCaml-cry

./configure --with-cry-dir=../ocaml-cry/src
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-cry-dir
configuring ocaml-cry 0.3.0
....
checking for ocamlfind... ocamlfind
checking for ocaml standard library path... /usr/lib/ocaml
checking for caml/threads.h... yes
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking for ocaml bytes module... configure: error: Not found.
```

I tried to find OCaml bytes module.. but I can't, as in attitude, as in google. How can I resolve this dependency?

Comment: Which version of ocaml do you use? Bytes are only there since 4.02.0. (http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Bytes.html)

Comment: I am on debian jessie, using OCaml version 4.01.0

Comment: So, I guess you should start by updating your ocaml, then try again.

Answer (score 1):

For those not having 4.02 yet:

```
https://github.com/chambart/ocaml-bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Théo pointed out, the Bytes module is new in OCaml 4.02.0.

Initially it's mostly a synonym for the String module.

If you add this:

```
module Bytes = String
```

to your code you might get it to compile.

Or you could update to a newer OCaml version.

Comment: I didn't mention this solution because that would mean changing liquisoap sources and I'm not sure it is a good idea.

Comment: No, of course, this is good to mention, it might be useful for someone, you are right!